# How to encode an xls file in base64?

Tags: php, curl, base64

I am encoding an xls file to base64 using php. Then I send it using curl to my server (using an API). I decode it, but when I download the file I get an unreadable file.

```
$xls = file_get_contents('/home/vacation/test.xls');

// Encode the image string data into base64
$data = base64_encode($xls);
```

Sending the file by curl

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/api/ -d 'data={//here goes a json with encoded file}'
```

Comment: how do you store it on the server side? the problem is PROBABLY there. also, why are you using json and base64-encoding? you should be using `multipart/form-data` instead, both curl (via the -F parameter, eg `curl -F data=@file http://example.com/api` ) and php (via $_FILES) have native support for uploading files with multipart/form-data, and you avoid the 33% overhead of base64 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-X POST` roughly translates to `CURLOPT_POST=>1` and `-d 'data={//here goes a json with encoded file}'` roughly translates to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>json_encode(array('data'=>'here goes encoded file'))`, so

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/api/');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        'data' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('/home/vacation/test.xls'))
    ))
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

.. but for uploading binary files you shouldn't be using json/base64 at all, you should be using multipart/form-data, whoever designed that api was probably not experienced at creating web apis, using json and base64 is a shitty design decision, imo. (worst part of it is that it uses roughly 33% more bandwidth than multipart/form-data would have, but multipart also has native support from curl cli with the -F parameter, and native support from PHP in the $_FILES parameter, and native support from php-curl with the CURLFile class. also it's difficult to make a json & base64-implementation where the entire file does not have to be in memory at once for creating the transfer request)

Comment: As I understand, they use base64 and json because you can send fileds AND files.

Comment: @pepe_botika69 so can multipart/form-data. here i send 1 file and 2 fields, look: https://i.imgur.com/1Mduir8.png